# How to set up Google Speech-to-text API?

Tags: google-api, google-api-client

I have access to the Google Speech Alpha API and I am trying to figure out how to set it up so I can send audio files and receive speech-to-text results from Google.

I requested and got access to the limited preview from https://cloud.google.com/speech/. I have a google cloud platform account, and I have experience using IBM Bluemix with Watson Speech API, and I am not sure how to set up a similar system for the Google Speech API.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Google Speech Alpha API isn't part of the apps-script side of Google so the question has a wrong tag.
Have you read the documentation? Do you have a specific question? What isn't working for you?

Comment: Thank you, I have changed my question. Let me know if it is still not clear enough.